# StringBuffer capacity()

Tags: java, stringbuffer, capacity

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

    System.out.println(sb.capacity());
    sb.append("abcabcabcabcabcabcab");
    System.out.println(sb.length());
    System.out.println(sb.capacity());
    System.out.println("-----");
    sb.append("abcabcabcabcabcabcab");
    System.out.println(sb.length());
    System.out.println(sb.capacity());
    System.out.println("-----");
    sb.trimToSize();
    System.out.println(sb.capacity());
    System.out.println(sb.length());
}
```

o/p is

```
16
20
34
-----
40
70
-----
40
40
```

My question is that in second line, the capacity should be 36(20+16). why is it showing as 34.

Comment: Your title and tags say *StringBuffer*. Your code says *StringBuilder*. Which is it?

Comment: Related: (if you did mean StringBuffer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011574/what-is-the-capacity-of-a-stringbuffer?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Javadoc, I don't think `StringBuilder` specifies how exactly it will grow, but what is most likely happening is that once it has to grow it calls [`ensureCapacity(minimumCapacity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#ensureCapacity-int-) which *is* documented:

> The new capacity is the larger of:
>
> - The minimumCapacity argument.
> - Twice the old capacity, plus 2.

So you go from the initial 16 to

- the new length (20)
- or twice the current capacity (16) plus 2

which ends up being 34.

But again, this is probably implementation-specific and not something you should depend on (or need to care about).

Comment: But after appending new text in other line, its length becomes 40 and now why is  it showing capacity as 70?

Comment: @RuchiGupta: Old capacity = 34, new capacity = (34 * 2) + 2 = 70. Where is the confusion!